# Max Java Heap Memory allocation size - are there limits?

Tags: jvm-arguments

-Xms100G -Xmx100G

I have requirement to create an in-memory database. The application is a Java application. Wanted to check if there are any other JVM arguments that needs to be set before the application can be allocated max and min HeapSize of greater than 100G.

Based on response from @harold I am editing the link so it becomes useful for others reading this post.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/parallel.html#sthref30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like that, but bear in mind allocating 100G from the launch of the application will make it launch slower, as it will attempt to allocate the full memory block at once.

Consider using a smaller value for the minimum heap size (Xms) so launch times are not impacted, as the VM will increment the size of the heap as required up to the value defined as maximum (Xmx) by itself.

Comment: Are there any limits to the max heap on 64 bit os. Theoretically, it should be 2^64 and it is quite high. But on Windows, it cannot be more than 32GB. True or not is something I want to find out.

Comment: That'd be the default maximum if you have above 128Gb of physical memory, according to the documentation (for the parallel garbage collector) - that does not forbid you from setting any higher limit. 
"Server JVM Default Initial and Maximum Heap Sizes (...) On 64-bit JVMs, the default maximum heap size can be up to 32 GB (...)  You can always set a higher or lower initial and maximum heap by specifying those values directly"

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/parallel.html#sthref30